# Access Gravity Forms fields on previous page (before pre-submit)

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Here's the sitch: I'm using a multi-page Gravity Form in conjunction with an external API.

On the first page of the form, the user supplies a phone number. On a subsequent page, I need to send the external API the phone number in order to retrieve the user's current settings, which then must be prepopulated in other fields.

I know how to use gform_post_paging, but since `$entry` hasn't been created yet I can't use it to pull fields from previous pages.

`gform_pre_submission/gform_after_submission` don't help me because I need to make the API call prior to users reaching the end of the form.

I've also tried handling this via jQuery, by pulling and storing the value of the phone field on page advancement `(e.g. var phoneNum = jQuery('#input_2_25').attr('value');)`, but I get "undefined" no matter what when using field ids. (It works fine, in the same location, looking for other ids on the site, so the issue isn't with jQuery.) I'm guessing this means that between pages, the form elements don't exist in the view?

How can I accomplish this goal (i.e., retrieving a value from a previous page in a multi-page Gravity Form prior to the user reaching the end of the form)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the data is stored in the $_POST variable on each page submission. Gravity Forms has a helper function for accessing $*POST data. The format for the variable name will be `'input`*{fieldId}'.

```
$value = rgpost( 'input_1' ); // replace "1" with your field ID
```

Comment: Many thanks. Didn't realize that got updated prior to the full form submit.

Comment: Follow-up issue: I've got the data I need, but can't figure out a way to get the information into fields on subsequent pages. gform_field_value seems only to work on initial form load, and I've also tried getting the dang values into a query string to dynamically populate that way, but since this is all being done in functions.php I can't seem to find a reliable way to refresh the page. Any thoughts?

Comment: Here is a snippet that does the trick: https://gist.github.com/spivurno/cee0e1c372bf988019e1 

I have a plugin that provides the ability to use merge tags in the default value field so that you can populate previous field values ([example](http://grab.by/M1y0). It's called [GP Preview Submission](http://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-preview-submission/).